# Force to call virtual base function instead of the overriden one

Tags: c#

In the following example "Test that v1 function was called" fails.  Is there a way to force call the base implementation of "RunFunction" through an instance of "class V2" ?

```
    class V1 
    {
        public virtual string RunFunction()
        {
            return "V1";
        }
    }

    class V2 : V1
    {
        public override string RunFunction()
        {
            return "V2";
        }
    }



    [Test]
    public void TestCall()
    {
        var v1 = (V1)new V2();
        var v2 = new V2();

        Assert.IsTrue(v1.RunFunction() == "V1", "Test that v1 function was called");
        Assert.IsTrue(v2.RunFunction() == "V2", "Test that v2 function was called");
    }
```

Thanks for looking, guys and gals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of class inheritance is that it allows you to override selected base class behavior.

You can use the `base` keyword from within `V2` to call into base-class code from `V1`, but you cannot do that outside of the class. Just as a quick example of usage:

```
class V2 : V1
{
    public override string RunFunction()
    {
        return base.RunFunction();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could instantiate an instance of `V1`:

```
var v1 = new V1();
```

Comment: Thanks.  But for my purposes, I have to call it through V2.  I cannot instantiate V1.

Comment: Is V1 an abstract class then?

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to do, but to access the `V1` base method via `V2`, you are going to have to modify `V2` somehow to provide a method or parameter that will trigger a call to `base.RunFunction()`.

Comment: I know it looks confusing, but I cannot explain why this is so, without opening a can of worms and taking hours of people's time to explain.  In a nutshell it has to do with the "Open/Closed Principle", Unit testing and Dependency Injection...

Comment: You may want to start with this article then:
http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html

Comment: @Rob Packwood, No V1 is not an abstract class.  I just can't instantiate it because I have no control over the instantiation of V1.  (yes I know I could but I'm not really "supposed" to do it directly)

Comment: @Rob Packwood, Thanks for that link, but I am already well aware of those design patterns.

Comment: If you need to call the method in V1 then something is wrong with V2.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel.  the call to V1 is for unit testing old code.  The call to V2 is for unit testing new code that is replacing old code, which have the same base functionality of V1 except for a couple of functions that have been re-factored, while keeping the original interface.

Comment: @Roberto - If that is the case, you need to set up unit tests that call into V1 to validate old functionality, as well as tests calling into V2 for new code.

Comment: For testing purposes why not use a new name for the new function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get away with `public new string RunFunction()` in the subclass, but I'd also suggest that if V2 isn't supposed to provide it's own specific behaviour, then using inheritance isn't the right approach.

You could also try defining a static on the base -- `public static string RunFuctionStatic(V1 item)`, then called as V1.RunFunctionStatic(v2Instace).

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish what you want with Reflection.

However, while it is unclear to me what your *ultimate* goal is, it is clear to me that you don't actually want to do what you're asking for. I suggest you spend some time re-educating yourself on polymorphism, and object oriented programming.

Comment: I know you may be confused as to what I am trying to do, Please read my comments  under @Justin Ethier's answer.